# ServiceStack.Redis Unable to tolerate Multi-Shard Azure Redis

Tags: azure, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

We are on ServiceStack.Redis version 5.14, on the .NET Framework stack, connected to Azure Redis v6.  Have been using ServiceStack.Redis since 2017.  We began seeing `ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException` errors (with a message contained `"MOVED 1340 <IP of our Redis instance>:1500"`) when we scaled our Azure Redis to the Premium SKU and then to 2 Shards.

Our connection string is not to a specific instance, it's just to the DNS name of the Azure Redis instance, port `6380`.

Does ServiceStack.Redis support multi-sharded Azure Redis implementations?

Answer (score 0):

[MOVED](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/#moved-redirection) is a Redis Cluster command, ServiceStack.Redis only supports [High availability with Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/docs/management/sentinel/), it doesn't support Redis Cluster.

Comment: Does Azure Redis have Redis Sentinel?

Comment: Redis Sentinel isn't needed in Azure's managed Redis as it has its own transparent high availability/failover solution in its standard primary/replica plans. Redis Sentinel could be [configured to run in Azure's Kubernetes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/run-scalable-and-resilient-redis-with-kubernetes-and-azure/ba-p/3247956) service but it still doesn't support multi-masters.

Comment: So if we have an Azure Redis instance that we scale out to >1 Shard, is there any way to connect successfully with ServiceStack.Redis ?

Comment: Multi masters require Redis Cluster, so no.